# Configure Apache CXF in Geronimo

Tags: apache, geronimo

I have installed `Apache Geronimo 3.0.1 with Tomcat 7 and Axis2` Application server to deploy my application. I made my application work in Geronimo. I want to know what are the components can be configure to Apache geronimo especially `Apache CXF`, Through [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Geronimo#Components) I come to know about component of Geronimo.

Now I want to configure `Apache CXF` in Geronimo. The link [Configure JAX-WS engine](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC20/configure-jax-ws-engine.html) says how to configure `Apache CXF` in Geronimo. Since I installed `Apache Geronimo 3.0.1 with Tomcat 7 and Axis2`, `Apache Axis2` is bundled with Apache Geronimo as per [given link](http://geronimo.apache.org/apache-geronimo-v301-release.html). So, I can't configure `cxf` in geronimo as per the procedure in `Configure JAX-WS engine` guide like

```
1.Remove the condition attribute and add the load="false" attribute to org.apache.geronimo.configs/axis2-deployer/2.0/car module.
2.Remove the condition attribute and add the load="true" attribute to org.apache.geronimo.configs/cxf-deployer/2.0/car module.
```

I did set the environment variable as well as

```
GERONIMO_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.geronimo.jaxws.provider=axis2"
```

but no use.

Can any one tell me how can I Configure Apache CXF in Geronimo and how to use this service in my application?

Note: I want to use `RESTfull Http` and [Local Transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/local-transport.html) service from `Apache cxf` that's why I wanted to use `Apache cxf` instead of `Apache axis`

Answer (score 0):

- Go to \var\config directory. Open config.xml file.
- check "org.apache.geronimo.configs/cxf/3.0.1/car", "org.apache.geronimo.configs/cxf-deployer/3.0.1/car"
- Set load="true" if it exist. Otherwise, Download and install it.
- Set GERONIMO_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.geronimo.jaxws.provider=cxf"